# Rails STI: Forbidding parent class initialization

Tags: ruby-on-rails, single-table-inheritance, activemodel

I have a rails model `Book`, with STI-inherited models `Fiction` and `NonFiction`

While book holds a lot of common logic, I'd like to forbid creation of the parent `Book` model. Just wondering about the most elegant method for doing that in Rails - any suggestions appreciated

Comment: It sounds like `Book` doesn't need to be a class at all a module instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could raise error in `Book`'s initializer

```
class Book
  def initialize *args
    raise "Can't create a Book" if self.class == Book
    super # if it's not the Book, proceed with ActiveRecord initialization
  end
end
```

Answer (score 3):

You can set it abstract:

```
class Book < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.abstract_class = true
  ...
end
```